# Database : Fetch two fields from same column on every array result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | pax          | travel_date |
+----+-------+--------------------+
| 1  | passenger1   | 2018-06-14  |
| 2  | passenger2   | 2018-06-14  |
| 3  | passenger3   | 2018-03-24  |
| 4  | passenger1   | 2018-03-16  |
| 5  | passenger1   | 2018-02-05  |
| 6  | passenger3   | 2018-01-11  |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

Above is my travel_manifest table, I want to fetch a list of those who have booked to travel and include their respective previous travel dates. I don't know how to include their respective previous travel dates in my query.

Below is my query,

```
$currentDate = '2018-05-14';

SELECT pax,travel_date FROM travel_manifest WHERE travel_date > 2018-05-14;
```

I'm looking for query result that looks like, e.g for passenger1

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => passenger1
    [travel_date] => 2018-05-14  
    [travel_date] => 2018-05-16 //previous travel date
)
```

Comment: Correction, the title should be - Fetch two data-sets from same column

Comment: I cannot see how the result set relates to the data set. And I wonder if 'previous' has some alternate meaning in your universe.

Comment: Strawberry, focus on the question

Comment: Please don't do that.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I think you may want to look into GROUP BY for SQL.
The part that makes your question difficult to answer is that none of the dates in your results match any of the dates in your example table.

Comment: I realised that after i had already posted, unfortunately there is no way to make correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, pax AS name, GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(travel_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS travel_dates 
FROM travel_manifest 
WHERE travel_date > '2018-03-15'
GROUP BY name
```

It will return something like this:

```
id  name        travel_dates
1   passenger1  2018-06-14,2018-03-16
2   passenger2  2018-06-14
3   passenger3  2018-03-24
```

In PHP you can then get an array of travel dates (assuming you fetch each row's data into the `$row` variable) with

```
$travel_dates = explode(',', $row['travel_dates']);
```

Note: I'm assuming the travel_date column is of `DATETIME` type.